# How to interface CAN protocol with arduino's in proteus?

Tags: embedded, arduino-uno, can-bus, proteus, proteus-erp

I used two arduino's interface with can module,input as 4 switch ,output as 3 led's.But not working.No error for code.But i think ,circuit in proteus is not correct.if i pressed 1&2 switch's the first,second led should be ON.if i pressed 3,4 the second,third led's should be On.why my circuit not working properly?

```
tSENDER

#include <SPI.h>
#include "mcp2515_can.h"

// CAN bus pins
const int CS_PIN = 10;
mcp2515_can CAN(CS_PIN);

int buttonState1= 0;
int buttonState2= 0;
int buttonState3= 0;
int buttonState4= 0;

const int ID1 = 0x01; // Right front door
const int ID2 = 0x02; // Right back door
const int ID3 = 0x03; // Left front door
const int ID4 = 0x04; // Left back door

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("CAN Sender");

  // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
  if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
    Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}
void sendCanMessage(int id);

void loop() {
   
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(2);
    buttonState2 = digitalRead(3);
    
   // Read the state of the push buttons and send CAN messages if necessary
   if (buttonState1 == HIGH || buttonState2 == HIGH) {
//    digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH); // Right doors indicator
    sendCanMessage(ID1);
    sendCanMessage(ID2);
  }
else{}
 buttonState3= digitalRead(4);
  buttonState4= digitalRead(5);

  if (buttonState3 == HIGH || buttonState4 == HIGH) {
        sendCanMessage(ID3);
        sendCanMessage(ID4);

  } else {
    
  }
   if (buttonState1 == HIGH || buttonState2 == HIGH || buttonState3 == HIGH || buttonState4 == HIGH) {

    sendCanMessage(ID1);
    sendCanMessage(ID2);
    sendCanMessage(ID3);
    sendCanMessage(ID4);

  } else {
  }
 

  delay(100);
}

void sendCanMessage(int id) {
  unsigned char data[] = {0x01};
  if (CAN.sendMsgBuf(id, 0, 1, data) == CAN_OK) {
    Serial.print("CAN message sent with ID ");
    Serial.println(id);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending CAN message");
  }
}





RECEIVER

#include <SPI.h>
#include "mcp2515_can.h"

#define CAN_CS_PIN 10

mcp2515_can CAN(CAN_CS_PIN);

const int LED1_PIN = 6; // Right doors indicator
const int LED2_PIN = 7; // Left door indicator
const int LED3_PIN = 8; // Interior light indicator
//const int R_TURN_PIN = 9; // Right turn indicator
//const int L_TURN_PIN = 11; // Left turn indicator

const int ID1 = 0x01; // Right front door
const int ID2 = 0x02; // Right back door
const int ID3 = 0x03; // Left front door
const int ID4 = 0x04; // Left back door

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED1_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3_PIN, OUTPUT);
 // pinMode(R_TURN_PIN, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(L_TURN_PIN, OUTPUT);

   Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("CAN Sender");

  // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
  if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
    Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}


void loop() {
  // Check for incoming CAN messages
  if (CAN_MSGAVAIL == CAN.checkReceive()) {
    // Read the incoming message and check the ID
    unsigned long msgId = 0;
    unsigned char len = 0;
    unsigned char buf[8];
    if (CAN.readMsgBuf(&len, buf) == CAN_OK) {
      msgId = CAN.getCanId();
      
      if (msgId == ID1 || msgId ==ID2) {
        // Right front door message
        digitalWrite(LED1_PIN, buf[0]);
      } else {
        // Right back door message
        digitalWrite(LED1_PIN, buf[0]);
      }  if ( msgId ==ID3|| msgId ==ID4) {
        // Left front door message
        digitalWrite(LED2_PIN, buf[0]);
      } else {
        // Left back door message
        digitalWrite(LED2_PIN, buf[0]);
      }
      if ( msgId ==ID1|| msgId ==ID2|| msgId ==ID3|| msgId ==ID4) {
           digitalWrite(LED3_PIN, buf[0]);
    }
    else{
              digitalWrite(LED3_PIN, buf[0]);
}}
  }}


ype here
```

i'm expecting,to get basic info about proteus and how to CAN module in proteus and what's wrong in circuit.